# How to correctly apply dragenter to an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to change the colour of a div when a drag an object over the div.

I would like it to go from red to green.

At the moment i have my **script.js**:

```
function dragEnter()
{
    $('.dropbin').bind('dragenter', function(){
        $(this).addClass('drag-enter');
    });
}
```

in my **general_notes.php** (which is the main displaying page here):

```
$("#dropbin").droppable
({
  accept: '#dragme', 
  drop: function(event) 
  {
    $('#dragme').hide();
    if (confirm('Delete the note?'))
    {
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'deleteNote.php',
        success: function(result)
            {
                alert("Success");
            }
      })
    }
  }
});
```

This **general_notes.php** includes a php file named **noteContent.php** this has this jQuery in it:

```
$('#dragme').each(function() 
    {
      $(this).draggable(
      {
        revert: 'invalid'

      });
    });

    $("#dragme").data({'originalLeft': $("#dragme").css('left'),
                      'origionalTop': $("#dragme").css('top')
                     });
```

and this is the call to the function:

```
<div class="dropbin" id="dropbin" ondragenter="dragEnter(event)">
            <span class="fa fa-trash-o noSelect hover-cursor" style="font-size: 20pt; line-height: 225px;">&nbsp;</span>
          </div>
```

At the moment it all works apart from the "dropbin" element does not turn green it just stays red. How can i make this turn green using the draggable element i currently have onto the droppable element i have?

Comment: i see nowhere the call to `dragEnter()` function which sets the event, is it in the document ready?

Comment: apologies, ive added that in

Comment: oh i see, this is not the right way. As it is, your `dragEnter()` sets the event listener on your element. If you don't call it as soon as the page is ready, the event listener will no be set. When you do `ondragenter="dragEnter(event)"`, it is the inline js equivalent to jQuery's setting a listener on this element. So as it is, JS sets an event listener when dragentered to lauch jQuery's function to set its event listener, one too many. It should actually turn green on the second drag.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below snippet in the script file:

```
$(document).on('dragenter','.dropbin', function(){
    $(this).addClass('drag-enter');
});
```

P.S: Do not keep the above snippet inside **dragEnter() function** and **ondragenter="dragEnter(event)"** from your html if you simply use it to add class.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a look at a couple pieces.

```
function dragEnter()
{
    $('.dropbin').bind('dragenter', function(){
        $(this).addClass('drag-enter');
    });
}
```

And

```
<div class="dropbin" id="dropbin" ondragenter="dragEnter(event)">
```

What this code is telling us is when you drag onto "dropbin", lets fire dragEnter. And dragEnter will register a function to the dragenter event. It won't fire because the event has already been triggered. Try this instead

```
function dragEnter(event)
{
  $(event.target).addClass('drag-enter');
}
```

Comment: hmmm, its still not doing anything, i even tried `$(this).css('background-color', 'green');` in the function since really thats all the class is adding but, theres nothing in the console and nothing changes

Comment: Fixed a mistake in the example at the bottom, try that.

Comment: it's still not doing anything :(

Comment: Ok so i  have it working, i realised you can simply add this one line to your "droppable" function  
`hoverClass: "drag-enter",`